# Laravel array inside Object

Tags: php, laravel

This is Array I want to display questions with foreche inside blade

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            
            "time": 20,
            "questions": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "type_id": 2,
                    "difficulty_id": 1,
                    "category_id": 1,
                    "second_category_id": 1,
                    "third_category_id": 0,
                    "question": "{\"ru\":\"sadsdasdaasd\"}",
                    "a": "{\"ru\":null}",
                    "b": "{\"ru\":null}",
                    "c": "{\"ru\":null}",
                    "d": "{\"ru\":null}",
                    "answer_written": null,
                    "answer": null,
```

LIke this

```
@foreach($questions->questions as $link)
              
@endforeach
```

But I can not display there some errors, How I can display give advise???

Comment: can you show controller code as well

Comment: It usually helps when *there some errors* to include the errors in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use like below

```
@foreach(json_decode($questions['data']['questions']) as $link)
```

Comment: I tried this thank you but , this type error "Undefined index: data"

Comment: `@foreach(json_decode($questions['data']['questions']) as $link)`

Comment: "Undefined index: data".  this also returned like this error

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have decoded the JSON to a PHP data structure, the first part of the JSON String denotes an object owning an object owning an array, so

```
foreach($questions->data[0]->questions as $link)
```